# Who are these characters with black-and-gold Iron Man?

Tags: marvel, character-identification

I only really recognize Iron Man in the centre, even though his armour looks to be black and yellow and not red and yellow.

[image]

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but the artwork seems to come from a cover for the *Rings of Mandarin* storyline: http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Iron_Man_Vol_5_28

Comment: If nobody else writes an answer, I might have a crack later – but the list of names in that Wiki article probably narrows it down quite a lot.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### The image itself is an alternate cover for the "[Rings of the Mandarins](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Iron_Man_Vol_5_28)" arc. These are the eponymous '[Mandarins](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Mandarin)'

The tall black guy is "[The Exile](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Victor_Kohl_(Earth-616))" (Victor Kohl - Mandarin 5)

[image]

The guy in gold is "[The Liar](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Marcus_Kumar_(Earth-616))" (Marcus Kumar - Mandarin 8)

[image]

The guy with lots of hands is "[The Fascist](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/marveldatabase/images/6/6e/Alec_Eiffel_%28Earth-616%29_from_Iron_Man_Vol_5_25_001.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140515204439)" (Alex Eiffel - Mandarin 3)

[image]

The guy with the crown hat is "[Mole Man](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Harvey_Elder_(Earth-616))" (Harvey Elder - Mandarin 6)

[image]

The guy with the gold glasses is "[Mandarin 2](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Colin_Sixty_(Earth-616))" (Colin Sixty)

[image]

And the guy in the green armour is "[Endotherm](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Thomas_Wilkins_(Earth-616))" (Thomas Wilikins - Mandarin 10)

[image]

Comment: And now I see the inspiration for several of the heroes in *Sentinels of the Multiverse*. Definitely Endotherm has got to be at least part of the idea for Absolute Zero.